# How to split one column with mixed values of integers and strings into two different columns using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis

| HEADER A | header B |
| --- | --- |
| test | A |
| test1 | B |
| test2 | 1 |
| test3 | E |
| test4 | 2 |

INTO

| HEADER A | header c | header d |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test | A | Nan |
| test1 | B | Nan |
| test2 | Nan | 1 |
| test3 | E | Nan |
| test4 | Nan | 2 |

In short i want to split header B INTO header c and header d as shown in the table. Using pandas

Comment: can you provide the output of `list(df['header B'])` for clarity?

Comment: it is around lakhs

Comment: Then `list(df['header B'].head(20))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) then with `Series.mask`

```py
df['header c'] = df['header B'].mask(df['header B'].str.isnumeric(), np.nan)
df['header d'] = df['header B'].where(df['header B'].str.isnumeric(), np.nan)
```

```
print(df)

  HEADER A header B header c header d
0     test        A        A      NaN
1    test1        B        B      NaN
2    test2        1      NaN        1
3    test3        E        E      NaN
4    test4        2      NaN        2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have strings, use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df[['header c', 'header b']] = df['header B'].str.extract(r'^(\D+)|(\d+)$')
```

output:

```
  HEADER A  header B header c header b
0     test         A        A      NaN
1    test1         B        B      NaN
2    test2         1      NaN        1
3    test3         E        E      NaN
4    test4         2      NaN        2
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but do we have any other methods other than string extraction? like integer extraction?.

Comment: As I said in the other comment, can you provide a sample in the requested format?

Comment: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] this is the output of header B right now, i have problem whenever i add a new string in this header it should be got splited